# Regex check which groups have been found

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
regex_pattern = r'^(?P<value>[\.\d]+)(\s+)(?P<unit>[a-zA-z/%]+)$'
            for row in data:
                name, value = re.search(regex_pattern, str(row[1]))
                if value is not None and unit is not None:
                    print(value, unit)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

I presume because it can't find any match, so I can check if the result is None.

But what if the `name` is found and not the `value` or vice-versa, how can I check ?

Comment: Neither of your capture groups are optional or conditional... so *both* will have to be there or else you get no match

Comment: Once you've resolved what you want to match or not and get a successful match, you might also want to do at the match objects `.groupdict()` which'll give you the name of the group->value of group look if you then wanted to do some checking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this returns None:

> name, value = re.search(regex_pattern, str(row[1]))

You can not unpack it into name and value. re-write your code as:

```py
search = re.search(regex_pattern, str(row[1]))
if search is not None:
    name, value = search
```

Thirdly, I don't know what `__unit__` is doing here. Did you mean to write name?

Alternatively, you can make you regex optional to return either name or value or both. Currently, it must return both.